# Centering views in code vs xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have this XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Coding!"
        android:textSize="42sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Which creates this:

[image]

I'm trying to recreate this in code. **Note:** I know it's recommended to use XML. I'm trying to create a tutorial that explains the various approaches to creating a layout, and I wanted to create the exact same layout in both just to demonstrate that it's possible.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
package io.happycoding.helloworldapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //textViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        textView.setText("Happy Coding!");
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 42);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //buttonParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        button.setText("Click me!");
        button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
        linearLayout.addView(button);

        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

This code creates this:

[image]

If I uncomment the gravity on the `TextView` and the `Button` (which I don't understand why I'd have to do, since it's not in the XML), I get this:

[image]

Which is closer, but still not centered vertically.

**My question is:** How can I horizontally and vertically center my views in a `LinearLayout` in code, so that it matches what the XML is doing? I'm trying to show that XML and code are doing the same thing, but apparently they're not. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: To replicate that XML, you want to call `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` on the `LinearLayout`, rather than fiddling with the individual `LayoutParams`. You can also omit the `LayoutParams` that you're setting on the `LinearLayout` itself. It will fill the content space, by default.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the reply. That did indeed work. Do you mind explaining why? What's the difference between setting `LayoutParams` and setting it directly? If you expand this into an answer I'll upvote and accept it. :p Either way thanks for your time, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Sure thing. Gimme a little bit to put something together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate the given XML, you want to call `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` on the `LinearLayout`, rather than fiddling with the individual child `View`s' `LayoutParams`.

For a `LinearLayout`, gravities on its children's `LayoutParams` that are in the same direction as the `LinearLayout`'s orientation are ignored, as `LinearLayout` just wants to plainly stack its children in the given direction. That is, for your vertically oriented `LinearLayout`, the vertical centering inherent to `Gravity.CENTER` has no effect, so only the horizontal centering is applied, when those lines are un-commented.

However, the gravity set on the `LinearLayout` itself is a different story. Though the children's individual gravities are ignored, the `LinearLayout` will still apply its own internal gravity to the children when they're laid out. That's why setting the gravity directly on the `LinearLayout` has the desired effect.

Also, you can also omit the `LayoutParams` that you're setting on the `LinearLayout`. It will fill the content space by default, and the `gravity` you're setting there isn't effecting anything, as it's telling the `LinearLayout`'s parent how to lay out the `LinearLayout` itself, not anything to do with its children.

Comment: Okay cool, so `LayoutParams` tell the parent layout what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly right. I wasn't sure how much to explain, since you obviously knew that the children needed `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. A `View`'s `LayoutParams` need to be the parent `ViewGroup`'s type, 'cause they're info for the parent. That also means that the `LayoutParams` you're currently setting on the `LinearLayout` itself are the wrong type, 'cause it's actually being put inside a `FrameLayout`, but that won't cause a crash, in this particular case. It might, though, in other situations, if, on a `View`, you have a `LayoutParams` type that's incompatible with the parent's `LayoutParams`.